# google maps Customized pins

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a map with Google from this:
[Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple)

But I would like to put in 8 more pins, that should illustrate the places I have been in the world. But I dont have an idea if I can do that from that code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var place_1 = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var place_2 = {lat: 55.971232, lng: 9.854725};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you can. What stops you from adding more pins to a map? The next example shows how to do it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated my question with code. I read the next example, but I am not quite sure how to use that code. Because that take beaches near Australia. I want customized pins. I tried to add place_2, but I should also call that somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I understand now. I think I need to get some sleep. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as many markers as you want:

```
function initMap() {
    //this is different:
    var places = new Array();
    places.push({lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044});
    places.push({lat: 55.971232, lng: 9.854725});
    //push all of remaining places

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    //and this is different:
    var markers = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < places.length; i++){
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng),
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      }));
    }
  }
```